# pyqt5 with unicode: make it compatible between python2 and python 3

Tags: python, unicode, pyqt, compatibility

I am trying to display some unicode letter in PyQt5 widgets, something like:

```
self.ui.lblImageName.setText(data['image'])
```

where `data['image']` is a unicode string read from a yaml config file.

However, when running using python2, I got the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u03bc' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If run the same program using python3, it works fine.

My question is, is there a way to make the code runnable from both python2 and python3?

Comment: Check out [`unicode_literals`](http://python-future.org/unicode_literals.html).

Comment: Looks like you need to fix the yaml so that it always uses unicode strings. See: [How to force PyYAML to load strings as unicode objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2890146/984421).

Comment: @a_guest importing `unicode_literals` solved the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you for the suggestion. I checked out the post and found it's pretty useful. In any case, as I am developing a new software targeting mainly python3, importing `unicode_literals` seems to be a better and cleaner solution.